# jQuery selecting an 'A' tag using .parents() function that contains onclick events

Tags: jquery

Even though I have found the issue to my problem, I am not able to find a solution to this.

Well, I have an 'Add to Cart' button which can take two forms of code as below:

```
CODE 1:
<div class="cart">
    <a class="button" onclick="addToCart('710'); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category Page', 'Add to Cart', 'Large Dual Fitting Pluto Metal Lighting Pendant Shades - Green']);">
        <span>Add to Basket</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and

```
CODE 2:
<div class="cart">
    <a class="button" onclick="addToCart('710');">
        <span>Add to Basket</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have a separate common.js file which has the function addToCart() defined. The particular code that I have issue with is this:

```
if (json['success']) {  
    html = '<div class="popup-cart-info"><div class="popup-close"><a alt="Close &amp; Continue" onclick="closeCart();" title="Close &amp; Continue" ><img src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/fancy_close.png"></a></div>';
    MainImg = $('a[onclick="addToCart(\'' + product_id + '\');"]').parents().find('.image a img');
    AltImg = $('a[onclick="addToCart(\'' + product_id + '\');"]').parent().parent().parent().find('.left .image a img');
    if(MainImg.length) {
        html += '<div class="cart-box-img"><img style="width:150px;" src="' + MainImg.attr('src') + '" /></div>';
    } else if(AltImg.length) {
        html += '<div class="cart-box-img"><img style="width:150px;" src="' + AltImg.attr('src') + '" /></div>';
    } else {
        html += '<div class="cart-box-img"><img style="width:130px;" src="image/no_image1.jpg" title="Image Unavailable" alt="Image Unavailable" /></div>';
    }
    html += '<div class="cart-box-succ-det">' + json['success'] + '</div>';
}
```

The bit where MainImg is being assigned seems to work with CODE2 but Not with CODE1. The only difference between the two is the _gaq.push() function. If I use FireBug in Firefox and remove the _gaq.push() function, it seems to work well. All I am trying to do is pass the image source of the product that has been added to cart. But it does not work when there is one more function next to it.

My question is how do I select the tag using the parents() function even when there are two functions defined in the onclick event.

You can see what I am trying to achieve at http://bit.ly/YEW2f2. The image is obtained for the 'New Arrivals' but not for 'Featured Products'.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks for looking.
Regards,
Karthick

Comment: put the track code inside `addtoCart()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector

```
a[onclick="addToCart('170');]
```

does of course not match

```
<a class="button" onclick="addToCart('710'); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cat ...
```

because the onclick attribute does not contain the *exact* text `a[onclick="addToCart('170');]`, but more than that.

To select an attribute when the content *begins* with a specified text, use the comparison "operator" `^=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot CBro. Knew that the solution was something so simple. Been trying to find a solution for over two days. Did learn a lot in the process though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ instead of [onclick=...]

Comment: even though this solves the question, had to select the other as it was more direct. Thanks.